# How to deny a specific user to reboot or shut down with sudo

Tags: redhat, sudo

Hello and thanks for helping me in this question. I just have in `/ets/sudoers` something like this:

```
# User Aliases
User_Alias CLIENT = jhonny 
CLIENT myserver = ALL. !ADMIN_CMD,!SU
```

I just want deny to jhonny the capacity to shut down or reboot the machine.

Server is Red Hat 6.6 Santiago.

Comment: The [manual](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html) might seem a bit heavy at first but still has some pretty good examples as well as the default sudoers file that Red hat provides. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1):

as far as i know, you will need to create a while list of commands available to the user via the sudoers file. a good start will be reviewing the manual: `man sudoers`

if you allow the user access to the ALL command alias, they can perform a number of work arounds, allowing them to gain access to what you are trying to deny.

if this isn't much of an issue, here is an example i found online (possibly from the man page?)

```
# From 'man sudoers'
Cmnd_Alias     SU = /usr/bin/su
Cmnd_Alias     SHELLS = /usr/bin/sh, /usr/bin/csh, /usr/bin/ksh, \
                                /usr/local/bin/tcsh, /usr/bin/rsh, \
                                /usr/local/bin/zsh

# jill may run any commands in the directory /usr/bin/ except for those
# commands belonging to the SU and SHELLS Cmnd_Aliases.
jill           ALL = /usr/bin/, !SU, !SHELLS
```

and as user255657 has said, this is with 100% certainty a duplicate.

Comment: `and as user255657 has said, this is with 100% certainty a duplicate.` - so why answer it?

Comment: if a thread is going to sit open, without an answer, what purpose is it serving? none. and what harm does it do to atleast provide a tid bit of useful information or a simple direction for somebody coming here from a search engine or site search? none

Comment: the problem with people posting duplicate questions is a real one. it wastes peoples time. but duplicate questions without answers are an even bigger wastes of time and results in even more empty space. in my opinion, creating a problem where there isn't one kills public forums just as quickly and lazy participants

Comment: Don't answer it -> flag as a duplicate -> it acts as a signpost. If you want to provide a _better_ answer than those that already exist - answer [the existing question](http://serverfault.com/questions/36759/editing-sudoers-file-to-restrict-a-users-commands). Having answers spread around duplicate questions does not help; it just dilutes information by making it harder to find.

Comment: @AD7six Amen brother!